# How to get tooltips working in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm a JQ noob. I am trying to get the `title` into a little tooltip, my finy fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/q52954vc/1/

I seem to also have some error in my jQuery code, but not sure where that is.
Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.hoverAble').hover(function(){

        var tip = "RRR "+$(this).attr('title');

        $('#myToolTip').html(tip).fadeIn();
        //$('#tooltip').css({ top : $('#link').offset().top + 10 + 'px' });

    }, function() {

        $('#myToolTip').fadeOut();

    }

});
```

Please help me get this working so that the tooltip appears next to the mouse pointer.

Comment: Updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q52954vc/2/  Just added a missing `)` at line 14

Comment: Thanks! But why does the text jump like that? I just want the tooltip to show at the side of the mouse...

Comment: That's not a real solution, just an example, but do you mean it should be displayed like that? http://jsfiddle.net/q52954vc/3/ And re the question why the text jumps - the tooltip is set to display none initially and set to display block on hover, so it's displayed on top of the div and moves the div down.

Comment: Thanks! That does look better but still a weird! Plus the title is displaying its text too after a few seconds :(

Comment: That's because the div with the text currently has 100% width. I've just added an adjusted Fiddle and an answer to avoid too many comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q52954vc/4/) again. Adjustments were to add CSS for the text:

```
.hoverAble
{
  display:inline;
}
```

so the div with the text has not 100% width as previously. I've added the jquery

```
    var tPos = $(this).width() + 20;
    $('#myToolTip').css({"left" : tPos});
```

before the tooltip fades in so the position of the tooltip is to the left of the div with the width of the div and added 20px as value for `left`.

**Update:** For the question in the comment if it's possible not to display the title on hover - just updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q52954vc/5/) with the following adjustments: in case you don't need to have a `title` attribute on the `<div>` and only used it to store the copy for the tooltip, just change it to a `data`-attribute like `data-title`:

```
<div class="hoverAble" data-title="I am blah!">sdddd</div>
```

and adjust the copy for the tooltip to retrieve the value of the `data-title` attribute:

```
var tip = "RRR " + $(this).data('title');
```

In case you really need the `title` attribute on the `<div>`, it's possible to remove it on hover and add it again with the value of the `data-title` attribute when the tooltip faded out.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to suppress the title showing after those 2 or so seconds? Maybe change the attribute?

Comment: Gotta go, if you figure out how to take out the title showing let me know, have picked your answer in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan Glad I was able to be of help. Just updated my answer for the issue with the title.